# Sources for learning how to use the SharePoint 2010 API?

Tags: 2010, development

Does anyone know of a resource/book/website/video series that's something like a "Non-developers guide to working with the SharePoint API"? I've looked a lot online for something like this but really haven't found anything that's geared towards non-developers.

I've been the front-end administrator for our SharePoint 2010 farm for about 18 months now, and more and more am being asked to step into the development world to build custom solutions. I have an HTML, CSS, some JS, and some Java background, and a lot of experience building OOTB solutions in SharePoint. Thanks for any recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you start with this book, **"Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010"**.

The first 4 chapters can be read online at MSDN this link: [Book landing page: Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff742318(v=office.14).aspx)